# RegEx and/or jQuery to allow specific format of string input

Tags: jquery, regex, mask

I'm trying to allow a certain format in an HTML text box.  This format must be 4 sets of numbers 0-99 separated by hyphens.  For example, 4-4-4-4 or 4-55-4-55 or 44-55-4-55.  I found this [qMask jQuery plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) and it gets me 99% of the way to where I want it.  However, in each numeric field, it will either accept 1 number or 2 numbers, not 1 number OR 2 numbers.

Here my code: `$("#lce").mask("9-9-9-9");` Results in accepting 1 number per block

I've also tried: `$("#lce").mask("99-99-99-99");` Results in requiring 2 numbers per block

And: `$("#lce").mask("9?-9?-9?-9?");` as well as alternating the 9's and ?'s either way results in accepting 1 number per block

Also tried specifying my own criteria to search for per that site:

`$.mask.definitions['i'] = "[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]";`

`$("#lce").mask("i-i-i-i");` Results in accepting 1 number per block.

Nothing I've done is working and I either don't know enough about RegEx to specify what I'm looking for or the plugin doesn't accept RegEx the way I would expect it to.

The goal is to have an input similar to entering a static IP in Windows computer.  You can type 1-3 characters and use the [period] key to move to the next block.

Anyone have any hints?  I've searched, but what I'm finding isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ruoso](https://github.com/ruoso/jquery-regex-mask-plugin) regular expression plugin (smaller than the one you linked to). 
Then use the following regex mask:

```
$("#yourInputFieldId").regexMask(/^(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-|\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}-|\d{1,2}){1}$/);
```